# How can a function call the function it "overrides"?

Tags: scripting, zsh, function

Suppose, for example, that `fpath` is set to

```
( $HOME/.zsh/my-functions /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions )
```

...and that both function-defining files `$HOME/.zsh/my-functions/quux` and `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/quux` exist.

(I'll refer to these two versions of `quux` as "the user's `quux`" and "the site's `quux`", respectively.)

Furthermore, let's assume that I've run

```
autoload -U quux
```

This means that, if I now run `quux`, the one that will be run is the user's `quux`.

The word "overrides" in this post title refers to the fact that, in such a situation, the user's `quux` "overrides" the site's `quux`.  (I could have "shadows" instead of "overrides".)

---

My question is: is there a way for the user's `quux` to, in turn, invoke the site's `quux`?  (In a typical scenario, the user's `quux` would massage the arguments passed to the site's `quux`, and/or massage the output produced by it.)

I'm looking for solutions that do not require modifying anything under `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/quux`.

**IMPORTANT:** The `fpath` used in this question is *just an example*.  In general, all we know is that one function reachable through `fpath` overrides (shadows) some other such function.

---

I've experimented with dastardly schemes where, e.g., `$HOME/.zsh/my-functions/quux` takes the general form

```
# one-time initialization
local body
body=$( SOMEHOW <???> GET SOURCE CODE OF OVERRIDDEN FUNCTION )
eval "overridden_quux () {
$body
}"

# self-re-definition (MWAH-HA-HA-HA-HAAAA!)
quux () {
    local massaged_args
    massaged_args=( $( MASSAGE ARGS "$@" ) )
    __overridden_quux "$massaged_args" | MASSAGE OUTPUT
}

# one-time re-invocation
quux "$@"
```

...but the results are very fragile, to say nothing of the ugliness of the approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way is to force the loading of the original function, rename it, and redefine it in your `.zshrc`, rather than having a function with the same name in your fpath. Note that in zsh, you don't need complex tricks involving `which`, `eval` and wondering about quoting to rename a function: simply use the [`functions` associative array](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-functions-2).

```
autoload -Uz +X quux
functions[overridden_quux]=$functions[quux]
quux () {
  … overridden_quux $@[@] …
}
```

If you want the function to be autoloaded from a file in fpath, it gets fiddly because you need to load the original without accessing the same fpath entry recursively. I don't have a better solution to propose than locally redefining `fpath`.

```
#autoload quux
functions[overridden_quux]=$(
    fpath=("${(@)fpath:#$HOME/*}")
    autoload -Uz +x quux
    print -r -- $functions[quux]
)
quux () {
  … overridden_quux $@[@] …
}
```

Comment: I had the strong suspicion that I was overcomplicating things, and you just proved it.  Beautiful answer.  Thanks.